# Rails controller error: "No Failure App Provided" when returning 401

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http, http-status-code-401, warden

In my controller I want to respond to an ajax request with an http 401 (unauthorized) error if the user is not logged in.  However, the code below throws a 500 internal server error instead.  Rails gives the error: "No Failure App Provided".

If I use other http error codes such as :bad_request (400) it works fine.  The problem seems to only be with 401 error codes.  Why is this?

```
if signed_in?
...
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { head :unauthorized }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your Warden configuration?

Comment: I am using the [Monban Gem](https://github.com/halogenandtoast/monban) using the default settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in the Monban gem I was using for authentication.  It is built on top of Warden but failed to configure a "Failure App" as required by that gem.

I raised the issue, and apparently it has been resolved.

https://github.com/halogenandtoast/monban/issues/3